# Для чего обычно используют переменную envp/environ в Си коде?

Tags: linux, c

Вот не могу придумать для себя сценарий использования данной переменной.
Наткнулся на такую штуку https://opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-209/openssh/openbsd-compat/setproctitle.c.auto.html
Хочу разобраться в сценариях использования. Вот зачем обычно используют setproctitle и environ, вроде как чем-то взаимосвязанные вещи.

Т.е, подытожим: Есть третий аргумент в int main(char* envp[])
Есть extern char **environ в чем между ними разница, каков сценарий использования, почему именно extern char **environ используют в коде по ссылке

Comment: вопрос не понятен...

Comment: Ну, именно `env` в коде и нет. А вообще - это все связано с *[переменными среды](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B)*... Работа с этими переменными - извлечение их значений и так далее...

Comment: Я поправил вопрос

Comment: переменные окружение - это грубо говоря массив строк. А массив строк хранится в `char**`. Это отвечает на часть вопросов?

Comment: @KoVadim Я знаю что такое переменные окружения. Я не вижу разницы между environ и envp. В чем между ними разница. Каков сценарий использования непосредственно в си коде у обоих переменных

Comment: environ - это extern переменная, ее могут использовать и другие. evnp - просто локальная переменная для местных нужд. Там, если правильно понимаю, параметры с командной строки переписываются в этот массив environ, а оригинальная командная строка подчищается. Зачем - а кто его знает.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/getenv

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Т.е, подытожим: Есть третий аргумент в int main(char* envp[]) Есть extern char **environ в чем между ними разница, каков сценарий использования, почему именно extern char **environ используют в коде по ссылке

Практической разницы, как таковой, нет.

С прикладной точки зрения «`envp`» доступен только как аргумент `main()`, а `environ` в любой точке программы.

С точки зрения стандартов:

- Для доступа к переменным окружения Си определяет только `getenv()`.
- POSIX определяет `environ`
- «`envp`» — ни как не стандартизирован, но широко распространён на разных системах.

Из всего этого я бы сделал заключение, что «`envp`» — это историческое наследие, которое попросту не стоит использовать в новых переносимых программах.

Comment: `envp` включен в стандарт С

Comment: @user7860670, нет, ЕМНИП он упомянут, но требованием ни какого стандарта он не является (под `envp` понимается третий аргументфункции `int main(int argc, char **argv, char** envp)`